# How can I detect direction and number of objects using Emgu?

Tags: c#, opencv, video-processing, emgucv

How can I detect direction and number of objects using Emgu?

Objects are moving in all directions (2D); and a camera is seeing these objects (on a 2D surface). Object may have little differences in shape but are similar enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Invoke `cvAbsDiff` on successive frames (may be on each `n`-th and `(n - gap)`-th frame) to detect changes and use thresholding in order to get a changes mask
2. For each frame call `cvUpdateMotionHistory` and pass obtained mask as an argument
3. To get motion segments (objects) and their orientation:

   1. call `cvCalcMotionGradient` passing motion history accumulated by previous calls
   2. Split motion into segments by `cvSegmentMotion` and for each segment calculate angle using `cvCalcGlobalOrientation`

Similar steps are coded in `motempl.c` example distributed within OpenCV library.

Update

I thought that they've implemented almost complete OpenCV binding and differencies in interface are the result of adding OOP. For instance here is an [AbsDiff](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.4.0.0/html/17b44e5d-44c9-9cc5-1418-e17c0ff64e3f.htm) method. However motion related stuff has different structure. Use `MotionInfo` method to get motion angle as in this [example](http://www.motoreitaliano.net/emgu/MotionDetection.vb.htm) (which I found with google search).

Comment: Would you please describe it using EmguCV. I do not know C and EmguCV is different than OpenCV. And sinece I am developing in C# I need EmguCV - as a .NET wrapper aroung OpenCV. But EmguCV has different classes and methods than you have named :(