# Motion detection and simple analysis with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, opencv, motion-detection

Lets assume that I have a video playing in canvas and I want to do some basic analysis on that video like edge detection, motion detection and general motion **direction**. How should I  approach this problem? Can you point me in the right direction to some simple algorithms and general ideas on how to implement them?

I'm assuming that those kinds of things aren't often coded in JS, so I'm not hoping for anything working out of the box.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [OpenCV library](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). Maybe you can then use Python with JavaScript. For that, see [Python WebBrowserProgramming](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming) and [Best way to integrate Python and JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683462/best-way-to-integrate-python-and-javascript).

Comment: Okay, so I found exactly what I was looking in there - http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html and more specifically, the CalcGlobalOrientation() function. But a few questions - why do I have to pass a mask as a parameter, and what's "mhi – Motion history image"?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880311/how-can-i-detect-direction-and-number-of-objects-using-emgu) has some on this type of task.

Comment: Hi, links are gone, subdomain is dead

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done detection is comparing one frame to the next. It is simple and effective but sometimes not very reliable. This project has some examples of motion detection algorithms: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Motion_Detection.aspx